# Imap-stars not visible in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, gmail-imap, flag

I have an Exchange server and two email clients: Outlook 2010 and Thunderbird. If I click to star a message in Thunderbird, this star is not visible in Outlook (nowhere).
The same happens is I use Gmail; restarting Outlook, and Thunderbird doesn't help.
Can you help me?